# Structural mechanics traction boundary condition question

Tags: boundary-conditions, solid-mechanics

In structural mechanics, are the boundary conditions "free surface," "Traction free", "stress free" all equivalent Neumann boundary conditions?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: Thanks. When applying a traction boundary condition, is the problem no longer unique?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The classical stress analysis problem must have displacement constraints (i.e. Dirichlet BC) over part of the boundary. If stresses are specified at all points on the boundary, the solution is no longer unique.

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify. I'm trying to compute displacement on a mesh. I have a mixture of Dirichlet&Neumann BCs. I use a layer of ghost cells, where I specify the Dirichlet BC. For Neumann BCs, I specify at the face of the ghost and real cell. I need to compute the corresponding ghost cell displacement given the face stress BC. Before computing the displacement, I compute the face gradient using Hooke's law and strain-displacement relationship. However this does NOT give a unique displacement gradient as I have 9 unknowns (9 displacement gradients) but only 6 knowns (6 distinct stress values).

Comment: I can write out the equations if the above description is ambiguous.

Comment: What are ghost cells? I  never heard this notion. Traction free is not equivalent to stress free in a strict sence.

Comment: @WenjinXing, Ghost cells are used in finite differences to impose Neumann boundary conditions some times. How are they different?