# Structural mechanics - traction free = Zero displacement gradient?

Tags: boundary-conditions, solid-mechanics

This is a follow up question to my question yesterday [Structural mechanics traction boundary condition question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28539/structural-mechanics-traction-boundary-condition-question)

Does a traction free boundary condition also mean that the displacement gradient is 0 where the boundary condition is applied? My thinking is that it does not because it seems you can have traction free (zero stress) surface with a non-zero displacement gradient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traction is defined as

$$
\mathbf{t} = \mathbf{n} \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma}
$$

In terms of components, the zero-traction condition is

$$
  t_j = \sum_i n_i \sigma_{ij} = 0
$$

From the above you can see that the stress components don't necessarily have to be zero for the traction to be zero.

For a **linear elastic** material,

$$
  \boldsymbol{\sigma} = \mathsf{C}:\nabla{\mathbf{u}}
$$

In component form,

$$
  \sigma_{ij} = \sum_k \sum_l C_{ijkl} \frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_l}
$$

Once again, since there is no requirement that all the $C_{ijkl}$ values have to be positive, you don't need all the displacement gradients to be zero for the stresses to be zero (which is not strictly necessary for zero-tractions anyway).

However, zero displacement gradients will lead to zero tractions.

Comment: Hmm. In my previous question, I concluded that traction free=stress free=free surface. Does traction free mean zero traction? Does stress free mean zero stress? If so, then doesn't this mean that traction free=zero stress?

Comment: Stress free = traction free but not vice versa.  It's more intuitive if you think in terms of balance of forces on a small element. Note that the momentum PDE is typically defined on an open set; so there are some subtle issues here, e.g., St. Venant principle.

Comment: Ahh got it. So then what is free surface? Is it zero stress? When I think of free surface, I think of the classical cantilever beam problem, where one end is fixed and the other surfaces are "free"

Comment: I believe these "free surfaces" exhibit zero stress (tangential and normal).

Comment: @David Yes, but just on that surface.